# What is the term for this literary device where a name is replaced by a description?

Tags: literary-device

I remember in school being taught a literary device while studying *Beowulf* where a name is replaced by a description ("wave-rider" instead of boat, a weapon being "life-ender", etc). I cannot for the life of me remember what it's called.

Answer (score 10):

This is commonly called an [epithet](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epithet):

> 1a: a characterizing word or phrase accompanying or occurring in place of the name of a person or thing

You may also be thinking of a [kenning](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kenning):

> : a metaphorical compound word or phrase (such as *swan-road* for *ocean*) used especially in Old English and Old Norse poetry

Comment: Yes, kenning is the word I would use to describe this

Comment: Very interesting! Ken, is a Scottish or Northern England term, meaning, "range of knowledge or perception", which is in turn, related to the Old Norse word "kenna", which means, " to perceive"

Comment: @C0ppert0p It's not just regional; phrases such as "outside one's ken" are fairly widespread in English (though perhaps not common). And there are many English cognates, including "can" and "know".

Comment: @Chris Hampton  All of the Greek gods had epithets. Their wikipedia entries typically list them in great detail. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermes